# Power Automate - Get Table returns "The ressource could not be found"

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I'm very new to Power Automate, and I really haven't been able to fix tis one.
I've got a set of Excel sheets, accessible by a Sharepoint folder. The idea of this is: when any one of these sheets is modified/added, I need to take the 1-line table in the sub-sheet called "Info", and copy it to another Excel file somewhere else in the Sharepoint.

For now, here's how I've tried to do it: first, list all tables in the modified Excel file. There's only one, so we know it's the good one. Then, for this table, list all lines in it. Same thing here, only one. That line will be copied to the table in the other Excel.
However, I just can't seem to get the table. It always says "The ressource couldn't be found", followed by the request IDs.

Here's a screencap of what my Automate looks like:

[image: An Automate, depicting exactly what was said before.]

If any of ya'll have any idea as to what might be the problem here, that'd be great. I'll e trying on my end too, and edit this post with the results.